# run wordpress function - update_post_meta() inside ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have ajax script to send form, I want to additionally run update_post_meta() function if success. I assume I can do this in ajax_response.php file, but this is not wordpress file, so wordpress functions don't work there.
Which way is better to run this script, inside this ajax script (below), or somehow in ajax_response.php (but how initialize wordpress in this file?)
Script below is inside wordpress page.

```
$('#postForm').submit(function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           grecaptcha.ready(function () {
               grecaptcha.execute('6Lcg9l8jAAAAAAp4KIczCJ8N_xkOezJt7LngYVgu', { action: 'submit' }).then(function (token) {

            $("#googleResponse").val(token);
        
           $.ajax({
                   url: '/wp-content/themes/zaproszenie/ajax_response.php',
                   type: 'post',
                   data: $('#postForm').serialize(),
                   dataType: 'json',
                   success: function(data){
                       if(data.response == 'success')
                       {
                            $("#response").css('border','1px solid green');
                            $("#response").css('background','#ffffff');
                            $("#response").text(data.msg);
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           $("#response").css('border','1px solid red');
                           $("#response").css('background','#ffffff');
                           $("#response").text(data.msg);
                       }
                   }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You can't use AJAX in WordPress like normal php/jQuery ajax. WordPress has a it's own way to register ajax actions, You can search for **How to Use Ajax in WordPress** in any of the search engine and learn how to use Ajax in WordPress.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: Wordpress is only temporary option, but for this temp solution I want to have control to update post meta after success. This whole function now works, but I don't know how to run wordpress function after success

Answer (score 0):

It's hard, and insecure, to include non-WordPress php programs in a theme or plugin. Some security systems will block access to such programs.

Your best bet in 2022 is to implement this using [WordPress's REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/).

Here's what you do:

From your client-side Javascript use `url: /wp-json/zaproszenie/v1/captcha` to post your form.  In this case `zaproszenie/v1` is called the *namespace* and `captcha` is called the *base route*.

In your theme you implement it with a class like this. You'll put this class in a file called `class-zaproszenie-controller.php`.

```php
class Zaproszenie_Controller extends WP_REST_Controller {
  private int $version;
  private string $base;
  public function init() {
    $this->version   = '1';
    $this->namespace = 'zaproszenie';
    $this->base      = 'captcha';
    $this->add_hooks();
  }

  private function add_hooks() {
    add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
      register_rest_route( "$this->namespace/v$this->version", "/$this->base",
      [ [ 'callback'            => [ $this, 'post' ],
          'methods'             => 'POST',
          'permission_callback' => '__return_true',
        ], ] ); 
    } );
  }

  /** The POST handler for /wp-json/zaproszenie/v1/captcha
   * @param WP_REST_Request $req
   * @return string
   */
  function post( WP_REST_Request $req ): string {
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php';
    $upload = $req->get_json_params();
    /* here $upload contains the data POSTed from Javascript */

    return json_encode( 'success' );
  }
}
```

Then, somewhere in your theme initialization code, do something like this:

```php
require_once 'class-zaprozenie-controller.php';
$rest = new Zaproszenie_Controller ();
$rest->init();
```

and you